# C++ : getline() function does not include last character/string when reading from a file

Tags: c++, file, delimiter, getline, istream

i have these words from a textfile each separated by a '\t' space.

I want to be able to print those words in separate lines

For example:
these are the words from the textfile:

```
hel lo    im    carlos
```

The result i want:

```
hel lo  
im
carlos
```

The result i'm getting:

```
hel lo 
im
```

here's the code:

```
string ReadString(ifstream &file){
    char buf[1024];
    file.getline(&(buf[0]), 1024, '\t');
    return string(buf);
}

main(){
    ifstream delimfile("new.txt");
    while(1){
        string words = ReadString(delimfile);
        if(delimfile.eof()==true)
            break;
        cout << words << endl;
    }
    delimfile.close();
}
```

all the help is appreciated

Comment: It would work OK if you put a tab after the last word.

Answer (score 4):

Your last read will read until the end of the file (since there's no `\t` for it to hit) and set the EOF bit. Then you test if the EOF bit is set and break out of the loop. Changing your condition to check `delimfile.fail()` would fix this (because `fail` is set when the read actually fails).

You could also move the outputting of the word above the condition, but that presumes that the reading from the file works, which is a bad way to write your code. Similarly, having an extra tab at the end of your file would make your code work, but only makes it safe from this problem.

However, if I was going to write this myself, I would write it like so:

```
while (std::getline(file, words, '\t')) {
  cout << words << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
while(1)
{
        string words = ReadString(delimfile);
        cout << words << endl;
        if(delimfile.eof()==true)
            break;
        //cout << words << endl;
}
```